# Lambda Layer 内の config を読む方法

Tags: python, aws-lambda

MySQL をみにいく Lambda が増えてきたので MySQL 接続までの共通コードと
接続設定ファイルを Layer 化したいです

```
/python/mysql.py
       /mysql.ini
       /pymysql
```

という構成の Layer を作って
mysql.py の中はこんな感じで mysql.ini を読むようにしたいのですが

```
import pymysql

import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('mysql.ini', encoding='utf-8')
config = config['DEFAULT']

def connect():
    return pymysql.connect(host    =config['db_host'],
                           user    =config['db_username'],
                           password=config['db_password'],
                           db      =config['db_name'],
                           charset =config['db_charset'])
```

これをメインの Lambda から

```
from mysql import connect

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  mysql = connect()
    :
```

という感じで読んでみたら layer 自体は呼べてるみたいなのですが layer 内で

```
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'db_host'
```

となってどうも mysql.ini の読み込みがうまくいってないみたいです
メインの Lambda 内で同じコード同じファイルをおいたときは読めてたので
設定ファイルが間違っているということはないはずです

layer 内においたファイルを configparser で読むことはできないのでしょうか

python は 3.7 です

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layer は AWS 上では /opt/ に配置されるみたいで
/opt/python/mysql.ini を指定すれば読めました

ただローカルでテスト実行するときに毎回このパスを変更するか
設定ファイルと /opt に配置しないといけなくなるので
Layer 内での相対パスで読める方法があったら教えていただきたいです